# Replacing data in json structure based on values

Tags: python, json

I have a file(myfile.txt) in the following format

```
{"click_id": 124, "created_at": "2017-02-03T10:51:33", "product_id": 97373, "product_price": 320.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "null"}
{"click_id": 125, "created_at": "2017-10-03T10:52:33", "product_id": 96373, "product_price": 20.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "London"}
{"click_id": 126, "created_at": "2017-10-03T11:50:33", "product_id": 88373, "product_price": 220.50, "user_id": 2, "ip": "London"}
```

The function :

```
def get_status(self, user_id, date):
        for rec in self.RECORDS:
            if rec['user_id'] == user_id and dt.datetime.strptime(rec['created_at'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') == date:
                return rec['status']
```

The above function returns the status based on input provided. The status can be `"Valid", "Invalid", "Old", "New"`

Is there a way to parse the `myfile.txt` and add the `status` key that is  returned by matching the `created_at` and `user_id` which is passed in the function `get_status` with the one in the `myfile.txt` ?

The output (myfile.txt):

```
{"click_id": 124, "created_at": "2017-02-03T10:51:33", "product_id": 97373, "product_price": 320.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "null","status":"New"}
    {"click_id": 125, "created_at": "2017-10-03T10:52:33", "product_id": 96373, "product_price": 20.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "London","status":"Old"}
    {"click_id": 126, "created_at": "2017-10-03T11:50:33", "product_id": 88373, "product_price": 220.50, "user_id": 2, "ip": "London","status":"Valid"}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to load and parse the file, mutate the JSON dictionary and then rewrite/serialize it to the same file?

Comment: @PAckerman Kind of, Yes

Comment: Is there a class involved with this? The parameters for the get_status function imply that it is part of a class.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your file is not valid JSON. Since it is a list, your objects should be contained within an array.

This will import the file, parse it and write it out to the same file. You just need to put the logic in to replace the status in the `for` loop.

```
import json

data_file = "myfile.txt"
data = open(data_file, "r+") #r+ so the file can be both read and written to
parsed_data = json.load(data)

for obj in parsed_data:
    obj['status'] = "modified status" #replace the status here according to your logic

new_data = json.dumps(parsed_data)
data.seek(0)
data.write(new_data)
data.truncate() #not entirely necessary
data.close()
```